# PHP call method from class in other class

Tags: php, class, methods, call

Code example:

```
<?php // class_database.php
class database
{
include("class_validation.php"); //this does not work
$val = new validation() //this does not work
    public function login($value)
    {
if($val->validate($value))
{
//do something
}
    }
}

<?php // class_validation.php
class validation
{
    public function validate($value)
    {
if($value > 50) return true;
return false;
    }
}
```

How do I delegate the class validation in class database? 
I do not wish to inherit (implement or extends) the class validation -> behavior in validation is not to be changed. 
I just want to use the methods from validation class. Any OOP solutions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just like your question yesterday, `$val` will not  be in scope in `public function login()`. You need to define `$val` inside the function, or as a class property and access via `$this->val` in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use include inside a class like that! Either include it at the beginning of the file ( my suggestion ) or use it one line before `$val = new validation();` call.

class_database.php:

```
<?php
    include("class_validation.php");

    class database
    {
        public function login($value)
        {
            $val = new validation();
            if($val->validate($value))
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

class_validation.php:

```
<?php
    class validation
    {
        public function validate($value)
        {
            if($value > 50)
                return true;

            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Bonus points for spotting the missing semi colon on `$val = new validation()`

Comment: I tried this before but didn't work. Tried it again and succeeded. Guess I did something wrong before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `include` outside the class. PHP does not allow classes within classes.

Try something like this :

Code example:

```
<?php 
include("class_validation.php"); // include outside the class declaration
// class_database.php
class database
{

$val = new validation()
    public function login($value)
    {
if($val->validate($value))
{
//do something
}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either put the `include()` outside your class (at the top of your page, class_database.php), or if your using a framework/autoloader you can call it by namespace:

**Option 1**

```
<?php
include('class_validation.php');
class database {

}
```

**Option 2**

```
namespace ThisCoolThing;
use \OtherCoolThing\validation;

class database { ... }
```